# Lucene and Turkish Characters

Tags: java, lucene

I want to make a search system. I am using Lucene, it is like speedy gonzales. But I have a problem. When I use Turkish Character's(ç,ş,ü,ö,ı,) in my words, Lucene doesn't return any result. But when I use non-Turkish Character's in my word, Lucene returns result.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into FoldingFilter's and Analyzer's. Lucene may be converting non-ascii characters to ascii when saving them to the index.

Not sure what version of Lucene you are using, would probably help with figuring out what's up.

Comment: Have you used Luke to take a look at how the documents are being stored? That would help you determine whether it is how the text is being stored or how the query text is being modified that is the issue.

Also, what Analyzers are you using when saving currently? Are you just using the StandardTokenizer and StandardAnalyzer?

Comment: I downloaded Luke and run it. Again, I run a test query with Turkish characters, but not return any results... Also I use SimpleAnalyzer.

Comment: Can you view a rebuilt version of a document and inspect the fields to see if the characters are being stored correctly? You can do this with reconstruct and edit: https://lingpipe.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/luke_1a.png

Comment: Yeah result is here: http://prntscr.com/9diylz 

Original string is: "kapatıp kapatıp"
Lucene index: "kapat�p kapat�p"